# What are various options / arguments for "./configure" in Linux

Tags: linux, configure

I have seen that while installing new software in Linux, I always have to use first `configure` it.

But sometimes we need to pass various options like I did today to install `lxml`:

```
./configure --with-python=/opt/python27/bin/python 
--prefix=/usr/local 
--with-libxml-prefix=/usr/local 
--with-libxml-include-prefix=/usr/local/include 
--with-libxml-libs-prefix=/usr/local/lib
```

Now I want to know that how will the person know that what type of paramaters like  `--with-python` can be used?
I mean:

1. Are those parameters same across all software packages or they vary software to software?
2. I even tried to read documentation as well, but no one mentions those parameters.

Comment: Look at the script: `less configure`

Comment: I can only speak in lay mans terms on this - but writing ./configure then accessing auto-complete (tab) you will get a list of possible options. These are most definately unique, depending on the actual software.

Comment: @Mikaveli: Seriously? It's an autogenerated script created to be as portable and robust (instead of readable) as possible, and hence extremely unreadable (just like the makefiles generated by it), not meant for manual inspection. `./configure --help` is the way to go. Just follow an abritary autotools tutorial, generate the configure script from its super-simple `configure.in` and try reading that.

Comment: @delnan: I've also seen a lot of manually created configure scripts too, so I always start by giving it a quick once over. :)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
./configure --help
```

That will show you all options for that particular `configure` script.

Comment: Never knew that was a standard practice...wow. I love that for applications and commands in the CLI, wonderful to know `./configure [OPTION]`s can be listed. Thanks for the answer

Comment: This doesn't appear to be exhaustive.  Ex:  "--disable-shared" isn't listed, but "--disable-FEATURE" is, but one must look elsewhere for what "FEATURE[s]" are available.  Which is what I'm looking for, and lead me here.  So now I must RTFM myself.

Comment: Help documentation is often deficient so while this is selected as the answer it isn't very helpful.  For instance, I've been searching for an article that tells me what path to provide to the typical -with-something options.  Is it the path to an install with lib, include sub-directories or path to the lib files?  It never seems obvious for each configure script for a particular 3rd party component.

Answer (score 4):

Some are the same across all configure scripts produced by Autoconf (which is most of them, but not all); for instance `--prefix` is basically universal.  Others are peculiar to the particular configure script.

Answer (score 3):

`./configure --help` is always helpful. But I would say more about that in some packages not only is there a `configure` script in **the top source directory** but also **the possible subdirectories**. So, for knowing all possible parameters which can be passed to the `configure` script in **the top source directory** you should also have a look at the `configure` scripts in each possible **subdirectory**.
For example, in **the top source directory** of [binutils-2.34](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.34.tar.gz) tarball there are `--with-sysroot` and `--with-lib-path` parameters with `configure` script. If you type `./configure --help` under **the top source directory**, there are no document items for both of them because they are documented in the `configure` script under the **subdirectory** `ld/`. So you should type `./ld/configure --help`.

Answer (score 1):

I know about `configure --help` but the information provided is "light". The following GNU resources contain useful additional information:

[Installation directory variables](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)

[Release process](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Managing-Releases.html#Managing-Releases)