# How to list features that can be enabled and disabled in ./configure script?

Tags: autotools

Lots of open source software is distributed in source code with autotools build system. In order to build such software i issue `./configure && make`. But for some software i need to build only subset of it - for example, in SRP i'm interested only in library and not in terminal or ftp client. To specify what to build `./configure` script accepts `--disable-`, `--enable-`, `--with-`, `--without-` etc command-line keys that are listed in `./configure --help`, "Features and packages" section.

Given third-party open source archive with `./configure` script is it any way i can easily get list of all features available to enable-disable? Of course such information is available in source code, for example in `makefile.am` and `makefile.in` - but they are huge and hard to read. Maybe easier way exist, something like `./configure --list-features`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are various options / arguments for "./configure" in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227875/what-are-various-options-arguments-for-configure-in-linux)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`./configure --help` will do the trick.

This shows any `--enable-X` or `--with-X` arguments that are defined using the macros `AC_ARG_ENABLE` or `AC_ARG_WITH`, as well as a list of environment variables that the configure script will pay attention to, such as `CC`.

In some large projects that are organized as a series of sub-projects each with their own configure script, you may need to do `./configure --help=recursive` to see all the features/packages for all the sub-projects.

Comment: But sometimes it displays only general help - does this means that i can't use any additional options? What about options like --with-gcc=clang that is not listed at all

Comment: That means there are no `--enable-X` or `--with-X` options defined. You can always run `CC=clang ./configure`; these variables are listed in the last section, labeled "Some influential environment variables".

Comment: This won't always work. For example I'm looking at one that describes '-disable-FEATURE', but does not give a list of "FEATURES".

Comment: It always shows `--disable-FEATURE` even when none are defined. If no specific FEATUREs are listed, then none are defined.

Comment: @ptomato, are you saying `./configure --help` shows all the possible FEATURES? Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted because there are, in fact, cases where an --enable-X can be used but is not documented in ./configure --help. For instance, I am trying to learn from "Linux From Scratch" and here (https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html) it mentions that I have to use options such as "--enable-initfini-array" but running ./configure --help | grep "array" doesn't return anything. ./configure --help | grep "FEATURE" only returns --disable-FEATURE and --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]

Comment: @Adrian Are you sure you are running the correct configure script? I cloned gcc and ran gcc/configure --help, and it definitely shows that option in the help text. Looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/acinclude.m4;h=f9f6a07b0402f5a1bfed251ea469e232da605218;hb=HEAD#l281 it's clearly intended to have help text

Comment: @ptomato I found the problem: I was running ./configure from the top directory instead of using the gcc/ subdirectory that you can find inside the gcc source code. My bad.
Here, have my upvote.

Oh crap. My vote is locked until you edit your answer. Can you add a &nbsp; ?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add some of the clarifications from the comments, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, if `configure.ac` uses the `AC_ARG_ENABLE` and `AC_ARG_WITH` macros, the options should show up in the help output. I don't know why a package would try to circumvent this, unless it's an old script. A search of the `configure.ac` or `configure.in` script for these macros might help.